# What precisely is the extra power afforded by using deeper nets?

Tags: circuit-complexity, machine-learning, lg.learning

For any choice of activation function (fix the choice for all the hidden nodes for both the following DNNs) do we know of functions which some $k$ (hidden layer) DNN can compute but a $(k-1)-$DNN can't? (for any $k$ and with no restriction on width on any of the two DNNs)

I am equally happy to know of results which pertain to width restrictions on either side or vary the activation function between the two sides.

---

I am not asking about approximation ability gaps like what have recently been proven by Elden and Shamir between $2-$DNN and $1-$DNN.

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04485

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a theorem that every real function can be approximated arbitrarily well by a 1-layer network. (I'll try to dig up a reference). But some problems, e.g. PARITY takes exponentially more nodes to do in fewer layers. (That is, as the number of inputs $n$ grows, if you fix $k$, then the number of nodes per layer goes exponentially. If you allow $k$ to grow with $n$ you only need constant nodes per layer.)

Comment: @ChandraChekuri Thanks! I was looking at that paper by Telgarsky. I was feeling that this is still an approximation bound and it is not a gap between depth $k$ and $k+1$. Its probably a gap between $k$ and $k/\log (k)$.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri Now there is this paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01491

Comment: Maybe this? https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07860 (Kane-Williams '15)

Comment: @ClementC. Maybe you want to see our paper here, https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2017/190/ where we extended and modified a lot of this Kane-Williams paper to work for real neural nets. The paper also has many other things which are not related to the Kane-Williams paper.